# Building nodes as 32bit on 64 bit machine

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey everyone!

I am using a node that was developed using a 32 bit closed source library.  I only have access to a 64bit computer, and there is no 64 bit version of the library.  I would like to build my node which depends on the 32 bit library as a 32 bit application in order to make this work.

I found this website which shows how to do it using rosbuild: https://code.ros.org/gf/project/ros/mailman/?_forum_action=ForumMessageBrowse&thread_id=26204&action=ListThreads&mailman_id=20

but I need a solution for catkin.  Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194096/building-nodes-as-32bit-on-64-bit-machine/) by [Robocop87](https://answers.ros.org/users/5183/robocop87/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2014-10-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That post suggests that setting the `-m32` compile and link flags will compile your node as a 32-bit executable.

Since catkin is pure cmake, you should be able to use [set_target_properties](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command:set_target_properties) to add `-m32` to the `LINK_FLAGS` and `COMPILE_FLAGS` properties on the node in question.

That said, this may not work very well if the ROS libraries that you're trying to link with are 64-bit. You may have to set up a separate workspace and build your node and all of its dependencies in 32-bit mode. In this case, you'll probably just want to set the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` globally when you call catkin_make.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robocop87](https://answers.ros.org/users/5183/robocop87/) on 2014-10-06**:
Sorry for the late response, I'm not familiar at all with cmake and the docs look pretty intimidating.  I'll give them a read and try it out.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-06**:
Yeah, cmake can be a bit intimidating, but it's a whole lot better than writing raw makefiles or trying to use autotools, particularly when you have a large project with complex cross-project dependencies.

**Comment by [Robocop87](https://answers.ros.org/users/5183/robocop87/) on 2014-10-06**:
Is it possible to use something like  ia32-libs to let me build my node as 64 bit but use the 32 bit library?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-06**:
No. ia32-libs is the older 32-bit compatibility libraries (before Debian had proper multi-arch support). The Kernel is capable of running 32- or 64-bit binaries, but binaries can't switch between 32- and 64-bit mode while running.

**Comment by [Asan A.](https://answers.ros.org/users/74365/asan-a./) on 2021-06-17**:
additional comment to above solution

set_target_properties(MyTarget PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-m32" LINK_FLAGS "-m32")